# creating a login system with python

Tags: python

so i am new to python and trying to create a simple login system which registers users and login but i am having trouble in password and username validation following is the code (note that i have divided my code in different modules because i am thinking  of implementing  it in future:

```
register module
import re
def register():
    with open('username.txt', mode='a')as user_file:
        username = input('Enter Username : ')
        user_file.write(f"{username}\n")
    with open('password.txt', mode='a')as pass_file:
        password = input('Enter Password: ')
        pattern= re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9@#!$%^&*]{8,}')
        if password==pattern.fullmatch(password):
            pass_file.write(f'{password}\n')
        else:
            print("your password should be atleast 8 characters long!")
```

```
login module
def login() :
    l_user = input('Username: ')
    l_pass = input('Password: ')
    with open('username.txt', mode='r')as user_file:
        for users in user_file:
            validate_u = user_file.readlines()
    with open('password.txt', mode='r')as pass_file:
        for passwords in pass_file:
            validate_p = pass_file.readlines()
    if l_user==validate_u and l_pass==validate_p:
        print('hello')
    else:
        print('login failed')
```

```
finally main module
import Enigma_Register
import Enigma_login

print('1-Login\n2-Register')
choice = int(input("enter choice: "))
if choice == 1:
    Enigma_login.login()

elif choice == 2:
    Enigma_Register.register()
    Enigma_login.login()
else:
    print('Invalid Choice!')
```

Comment: What's your problem / question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your login function, replace the last four lines with:

```
if l_user+"\n" in validate_u: #ReadLines() adds newlines
   user_num = validate_u.index(l_user+"\n")
   if l_pass+"\n" == validate_p[user_num]:
      print("Password correct!")
   else:
      print("Password incorrect!")
else:
   print("Cannot find your username!")
```

also, the `for users in user_file` and `for passwords in pass_file` are unnecessary: just put the `readlines()` method on its own, without a loop.

Additionally, replace the `if password==pattern.fullmatch` with `if pattern.match(password)`.

I'd also suggest moving the file writes until *after* you've validated the password, otherwise "ghost usernames" with no passwords could appear, easily causing problems; or you could replace all of the code in your `register()` function after `password = input("Enter password: ")` with

```
pattern = re.compile( [YOUR REGEX HERE] )
while not pattern.match(password):
  print("Your password is invalid.")
pass_file.write(f'{password}\n')
user_file.write(f'{username}\n')
```

Comment: also if u dont mind i am having trouble understanding your if statements can u explain

Comment: also your after adding your code it gives a list index out of range error and password is not written in password .txt file

Comment: Hi, glad to help! When you got `validate_u = user_file.readlines()`, you received a list of usernames. The first `if` checks if the input username was one of the usernames in the file. If so, it gets the index of the username (`validate_u.index()`) and stores it. It then gets the password associated with that username by getting the password with the same index. If they are the same, the password and username are correct. The `\n`s are to fix the nasty bug caused by a quirk in `readlines()`, in that it puts a `\n` at the end of each value. The "value+\n" negates that.

Comment: The `IndexOutOfRangeError` is caused when you enter a bad password. This is because your code writes the input username before checking the password. If it _was_ a bad password, you get a username in the database without a password to go with it. To fix this, move the `user_file.write()` to _after_ you've validated the password. See my post for an alternative solution to this.